# math mode in ticks ( tikzpicture )

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I plotted the following function:

[image]

Here is the script used:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xlabel={traffic load},
    ylabel={M},
    xtick={0,1,...,5},
    ytick={0,1,...,5},
    ]
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=blue]
    coordinates {(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(2,1)(2,2)(3,2)(3,3)(4,3)};
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

I want that instead of having numbers in ticks, to have something that looks like:

[image]

How can I get the math mode in the ticks ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `xticklabels` and `yticklabels` for that.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
xlabel={traffic load},
ylabel={$M$},xmax=4.5,ymax=3.5,
xtick={1,4},xticklabels={$\rho_\mathrm{min}$,$\rho_\mathrm{max}$},
ytick={0,3},yticklabels={$0$,$M_\mathrm{max}$}
]
\addplot [mark=none,draw=blue]
coordinates {(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(2,1)(2,2)(3,2)(3,3)(4,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]